# How to remove a button from UITableViewCell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I have customized a `UITableViewCell` in that I have a `UILabel` and `UIButton`. I have set the frame in `layoutSubviews` method now that table has customized `UITableViewCell` that I am using in three places, but I need to remove `UIButton` in second place. How to do that ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomPopTableViewCell *cell = (CustomPopTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[CustomPopTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    if(tableView.tag == e_metadataView)
    {
        //cell.mCheakMarkButton.frame=CGRectZero;
        cell.mTaggedTerm.text = [docInfoCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if(tableView.tag == e_searchSettingView)        
    {
        if(indexPath.row == self.currentRow)
        {
            [cell.mcheckMarkButton removeFromSuperView];
        }
        cell.mTaggedTerm.text = [searchEngineCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if(tableView.tag == e_TaggedTermView)//tageed term table
    {
        TaggedItems *taggedItem = [documentData.taggedWords objectAtIndex : indexPath.row];
        cell.mTaggedTerm.text = taggedItem.keyword;
        if([self isTappedObjectExist:indexPath.row])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }


    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use :

```
for (UIView* v in cell.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [v removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

To be amended if you have an intermediary level of view in your custom cell of course. If you have several buttons I would use a tag to identify it.

Comment: its is removeFromSuperview , "v" is small :)